# Running Javascript function with Shopify on page load

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a javascript function that I want to run on page load on my Shopify website, it checks if the user's username is longer than 24 characters, and if so breaks it onto two lines:

```
function checkName () {

    var customerName = document.getElementById('customername');

    if (customerName.innerHTML.length >= 24) {
        var length = customerName.innerHTML.length;
        var middle = Math.floor(length / 2);
        var firstHalf = customerName.innerHTML.slice(0, middle);
        var secondHalf = customerName.innerHTML.slice(middle);
        customerName.innerHTML = firstHalf + '<br />' + secondHalf;
    }
}

checkName();
```

When I run this in the console, it works fine. But linking to it as a file on my site gives me:

> TypeError: customerName is null

I'm thinking that it's because it takes a second for Shopify to get the username and populate the element I tried adding `setTimeout` in different places of the function - but it still resulted in null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have that script in the `<head>` tag.  Place it just before the end of `<body>`.  Remember, browsers read from top to bottom, so if you try to select an element with the id of `customername` before the browser has found it, it will return `null`.

Alternatively, you could only call the function when the page has finished loading with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkName);
```

Which will only run `checkName` when all of your HTML has been parsed (including the element with the id of `customername`).

Comment: No problem.  I find a lot of beginners hit this issue.